# How to change the value of columns in certain rows in a pandas dataframe based off of the corresponding values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file containing a column of 'url' and a column of 'label'.
I have another CSV file containing a subset of the above URLs with the correct labels, and I want to transfer the correct labels to the main CSV file.

For every URL in the main CSV that is also in the second CSV, I want to find the row containing that URL in the second CSV and assign that label to the URL in the main file.

It's my first time using `pandas`, and my ideas so far haven't worked.
Is this possible without explicit for loops?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `df.update` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

As you described, the fields in the 2 files are identical, otherwise it doesn't work.
As often happens there are different ways to do the same thing. I agree with @algebruh's comment, df.update is the shortest way.
Here the code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')

df1.set_index('url', inplace=True)

df1.update(df2.set_index('url'))

df1.reset_index()
```

I hope to be proved helpful